# Efficiently extract value from meta tags given as string in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, meta-tags

I have a couple of meta tags stored in a string. Here is an example:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-04-08T09:00:01+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Alt value for the Article Image" />
```

There are many other such tags but I am only interested in getting the value of `og:updated_time`. Once I have the value, I need to compare it with some other value and finally replace the original timestamp with a new valuer if certain conditions are met.

I can use `preg_replace_callback` but it will be very messy to extract the value of `og:updated_time` and `article:modified_time`. Is there a cleaner and easier way to do the same thing?

This is the only value that, I need to extract. Won't it be easier to do this using some sort of string manipulation instead of converting the string to HTML first?

Comment: Always use a parser for HTML/XML parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @user3783243 I need a single value. There is no other DOM manipulation involved. Converting these tags to HTML and extracting the value seems to be overkill.

Comment: See user notes on https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.get-meta-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely fixed on using regex, you could do the following and use group 1 capture:

```
<meta\s+property=\"og:updated_time\"\s+content=\"([^"]+)\"
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/jK5wU3/8

Answer (score 0):

> Converting these tags to HTML

These tags are already HTML so no converting is done.

You can use domdocument to get the element you are after like this:

```
$html = '<meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-04-08T09:00:01+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Alt value for the Article Image" />';
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$metas = $dom->getelementsbytagname('meta');
foreach($metas as $meta) {
    if($meta->getattribute('property') == 'og:updated_time') {
        echo $meta->getattribute('content');
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/SeiMe

You also could use xpath to simplify it (if you consider xpath simpler).

```
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('//meta[@property="og:updated_time"]/@content')[0]->nodeValue;
```

https://3v4l.org/fFFuT

Answer (score 0):

While regex in this case may be perfectly stable for your very predictable collection of meta tags, we like to recommend DomDocument for stability.  I will also recommend XPath for ease of element accessibility.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RiMZj))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-04-08T09:00:01+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2018-10-01T07:33:20+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://link-to-the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Alt value for the Article Image" />
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html,  LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);  // omit unwanted doctype tags, but allow <html> for output readability
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$modified_node = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="article:modified_time"]')[0];
$modified_value = $modified_node->getAttribute('content');
$updated_node = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="og:updated_time"]')[0];
$updated_value = $updated_node->getAttribute('content');

/*
if (convert($user_value) > convert($modified_time) || convert($user_value) > convert($updated_time)) {
*/
    $modified_node->setAttribute('content', 'fresh');
    $updated_node->setAttribute('content', 'new');
/* } */

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html><head><meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-04-08T09:00:01+00:00">
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="fresh">
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="new">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-the-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://link-to-the-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Alt value for the Article Image"></head></html>
```

Now this adds `<html><head>` and `</head></html>` tags (because they were missing from your sample input), but I'm imagining that they are already there in your actual markup.

You weren't clear about your conditional logic, so I've commented out where that portion should be written.

My solution uses two xpath queries to target the two desired meta tag elements, then it extracts the `content` attribute value from each so that you can perform your comparison logic.  If the data qualifies, you then set the new `content` attribute values to your desired value(s).

Call `saveHTML()` to see the updated html structure.